# How to create a addline method?

Tags: java

I am having issues with my assignment about adding a new line using the below lines 1 through 4, as instances of `InvoiceLine` class into my `Invoice` class.

Instance Variables:

- Line1: a variable of type InvoiceLine class
- Line2: a variable of type InvoiceLine class.
- Line3: a variable of type InvoiceLine class.
- Line4: a variable of type InvoiceLine class.

`addLine` is a method that takes the following four input parameters: item number, item description, item price, and quantity.

The method then adds a line to the invoice only if the invoice has less than four lines. If the invoice already has four lines, then this method should print an error message.

How would I do it to make it work properly? I would appreciate any help.

Invoice Class:

```
public class Invoice {
    // Instance Variables
    private String customerName;
    private int numItems;
    private InvoiceLine line1;
    private InvoiceLine line2;
    private InvoiceLine line3;
    private InvoiceLine line4;

    // Contructors
    public Invoice(){}

    public Invoice(String customerNam){
        customerName = customerNam;
    }

    //Getters
    public String getCustomerName(){
        return customerName;
    }

    //Setters 
    private void setCustomerName(String customerNam){
        customerName = customerNam;
    }

    public void addLine(int itemNum, String Description, double itemPrice, int quantity){
        if (numItems <= 4) {
            numItems += line1;
            if (numItems <= 4)
                numItems += line2;
                if (numItems <= 4)
                    numItems += line3;
                    if (numItems <= 4)
                        numItems += line4;
        }

        if (numItems == 4){
            System.out.print("Error");
        }
    }

    public double getInvoiceTotal(){
        numItems *= numItems;
        return numItems;
    }

    public String toString(){
        String invoiceOutput = "";
        invoiceOutput += (customerName + " brought "+ numItems);
        return invoiceOutput;
    }
}
```

InvoiceLine Class:

```
public class InvoiceLine {
    //Instance Variables
    private Item itemSold;
    private int quantity;
    public double total = 0;

    // Constructors
    public InvoiceLine(){}

    public InvoiceLine(Item itemSold, int quantity){
        this.itemSold = itemSold;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public InvoiceLine(int itemNum, String itemDescription, double itemPrice, int quantity){
        this.itemSold = new Item(itemNum, itemDescription, itemPrice);
        this.quantity = quantity;   
    }

    //Getters 
    public Item getItemSold() {
        return itemSold;
    }

    public int getQuantity(){
        return quantity;
    }

    //Setters
    private void setItemSold(Item itemSold){
        this.itemSold = itemSold;
    }

    private void setQuantity(int quantity){
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    // Methods
    public double getLineTotal(double total){
        total = (quantity * itemSold.getItemPrice());
        return total;
    }

    public String toString(){
        String invoiceLine = "";
        invoiceLine = (itemSold + " brought "+ quantity + ", which the total cost is "+ total);
        return invoiceLine;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you will want to go back through your `addLine` method. Based on the description you provided for this method (which I assume is from your assignment), it sounds like this method should just set one of your `InvoiceLine` instance variables for that `Invoice`. I don't want to just write the solution for you as this is for an assignment so the point is to learn from doing! But here are some tips for where to focus:

- Pay attention to the instance variable types in your `Invoice` class. You are trying to "add" these to your `numItems` variable, which has type `int`. This wont work well!
- You shouldn't need to worry about checking the `numItems` value more than once in the `addLines` method. Once you check it and see it is less than 4, you know you should have available lines to add!
- If you are **adding** lines, you need to be **creating** some new `InvoiceLine`s. Take a look at one of your constructors for that class. You should see one of those would work well for the parameters you are given in the `addLine` method.

One important thing I'll point out though that should help you avoid more tedious hiccups: you are going to want to initialize your `numItems` variable to 0! You can either do this in the constructors or just set its default value in its declaration, like so: `private int numItems = 0;`.

Then, remember **you** have to increment/decrement this variable in your methods whenever a line is added or removed, it's not automatic. So the last thing you will want to do in your `addLine` method is `numItems++`. But only if everything was added successfully! (In otherwords, if the method wasn't actually able to add a line because there were already 4, you don't want to increment the `numItems`).

Hope that helps point you in the right direction! I'd give it another shot and see how far you get. If you run into other specific issues you can't figure out, feel free to comment.

Comment: Ok, I got it to work now. But it is null and there are suppose to have values when I print it out. for (itemNum = 0; itemNum < 4; itemNum++)
  System.out.println(line1);
  if (itemNum > 4)
   System.out.print("Error!");

Comment: @SilentWolf Can you make an Edit to your question and add at the bottom your new code for `addLine`? That would probably be easiest.